# Handling huge mysql query : Group BY sensitive

Tags: php, mysql

I have to run this Mysql query on my website to fetch huge amount of data: (3 tables , each with 100,000 + records)

```
SELECT on_resume.*, on_users.subscribed, on_users.user_avatar, on_resume_page.*
FROM on_resume 
LEFT JOIN on_users ON (on_resume.resume_userid = on_users.user_id ) 
LEFT JOIN on_resume_page  ON ( on_resume.resume_userid = on_resume_page.resume_userid)
WHERE on_resume.active= '1' 
GROUP BY on_resume.rid 
ORDER BY on_resume.rid DESC 
LIMIT 0,18
```

The time I run this at Phpmyadmin sql section, the whole mysqld service will be down and needs to be restarted.

Now I was testing this query and I found out if I don't use `Group by` and `Order by` conditions the query will be fine.

```
SELECT on_resume.*, on_users.subscribed, on_users.user_avatar, on_resume_page.*
FROM on_resume 
LEFT JOIN on_users ON (on_resume.resume_userid = on_users.user_id ) 
LEFT JOIN on_resume_page  ON ( on_resume.resume_userid = on_resume_page.resume_userid)
WHERE on_resume.active= '1' 
LIMIT 0,18
```

> Showing rows 0 - 17 ( 18 total, Query took 0.4248 sec)

Why is it like this and how can I fix it?...

**NOTE :** I have tested the SQL query with group by or Order by alone in either case , even with one of them still the query fails and hangs the server.

**EDIT** : This problem is solved by making column `on_resume_page.resume_userid` indexed.

Comment: You should be getting an error... you have items in your select clause that are not in your group by

Comment: So how should I use group by ?  or why when I delete group by still with order by I can't run this query ?

Comment: is your on_resume.rid a primary key?  Is it indexed?

Comment: You need to show us the table and index definitions.  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: group by is usually used in conjunction with aggregate function like count(), avg(), sum(), etc... it doesn't look like you'd need to use the group by from the looks of your query... the other point though is you are joining a large amount of data and then performing an order by if things aren't properly indexed this will take a while... when you remove the 'order by', it just grabs the first 18 rows that matches the criteria... how about running: EXPLAIN (then you sql statement) and posting what you get

Comment: @JerInChicago I ran EXPLAIN  and I didn't get anything useful, Where can I post the table to show you ?

Comment: I can't believe it , by making on_resume_page.resume_userid as INDEX , the problem is solved , now the query runs like heaven even with group by and order by

Comment: yeah - that's good... if things aren't indexed right that query will kill a server giving the illusion that it is hanging when in reality it is doing a ton of work that will take a while.

Comment: @JerInChicago Thanks for the hints , I wasn't thinking right till you told me to check the indexes !

Comment: @JerInChicago: MySQL allows you to put [unaggregated columns in the SELECT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) that aren't in the GROUP BY clause. It doesn't raise an error. The result is indeterminate. *They* call this an extension to standard SQL; I won't tell you what *I* call it. [PostgreSQL *also* allows this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY), but requires unaggregated columns to be functionally dependent on the grouped columns. PostgreSQL's behavior is determinate, and it's in line with current SQL standards.

Comment: A missing index shouldn't hang the server. I think a bug report is called for.

Comment: @Catcall No that was it, I test this issue on two on my servers. The left join conditions must have index marks .

Comment: @MacTaylor: I didn't say a missing index wasn't your problem. I said a missing index shouldn't hang the server. That's a bug, and you ought to report it.

Comment: @MacTaylor Please write an answer and accept it so that the people seeing this question can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was told, took a while to figure it out:
Look at @jer in Chicago comment

Remember, when there is a GROUP BY clause, there are certain rules that apply for grouping columns. One of those rules is "The Single-Value Rule" -- every column named in the SELECT list must also be a grouping column unless it is an argument for one of the set functions. MySQL extends standard SQL by allowing you to use columns or calculations in a SELECT list that don't appear in a GROUP BY clause. However, we are warned not to use this feature unless the columns you omit from the GROUP BY clause are not unique in the group because you will get unpredictable results.